# Merge two 2d arrays grouping on one column value and summing another column value within each group

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum, unique

Basically I need to take two arrays, merge them with unique values and sum one of columns. It makes more sense when written out below:

```
$a = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'Count' => 2],
];

$b = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'Count' => 4],
    ['ID' => 2, 'Count' => 3]
];
```

and I need the final product to be:

```
$a_plus_b = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'Count' => 6],
    ['ID' => 2, 'Count' => 3]
];
```

I have been playing with different variations of `array_merge()` and `array_unique()`, but I can't find an *efficient* way to do what I need. I know I can always do nested loops, but I was hoping for something easier. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

**Note:** This solution requires PHP `>= 5.3`. There is a PHP < 5.3 solution below.

```
$input = array($a, $b);
// add as many result arrays to $input as you want; e.g.,
// $input = array($a, $b, $c, $d);

$output = array_count_values(
  call_user_func_array(
    'array_merge',
     array_map(
       function($arr) {
         return array_fill(0, $arr['Count'], $arr['ID']);
       },
       call_user_func_array(
         'array_merge',
         $input
       )
     )
  )
);

print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 3
)
```

**Note** the array keys above are `ID` values. The array values are `Count` values.

---

If you're running PHP `< 5.2` you won't be able to use the inline closure with `array_fill`. You have to define it as a separate function.

```
$input = array($a, $b);

function _fill($arr) {
  return array_fill(0, $arr['Count'], $arr['ID']);
}

$output = array_count_values(
  call_user_func_array(
    'array_merge',
    array_map(
      '_fill',
      call_user_func_array(
        'array_merge',
        $input
      )
    )
  )
);

print_r($output);
```

---

From here, converting the output to your desired format is a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't over-engineer such a basic task.  Iterate both array with a single loop and assign temporary keys using `ID` values.  If encountering a respective `ID` key more than once, just add the new `Count` value to the stored value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9N5WV))

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($a, $b) as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['ID']])) {
        $result[$row['ID']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['ID']]['Count'] += $row['Count'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 1,
    'Count' => 6,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 2,
    'Count' => 3,
  ),
)
```

---

Functional programming can be used as well to achieve the same result -- `array_reduce()` is ideal since the number of elements in the output will be equal to or less than the number of elements in the input data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lUoOL))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            array_merge($a, $b),
            function ($result, $row) {
                if (!isset($result[$row['ID']])) {
                    $result[$row['ID']] = $row;
                } else {
                    $result[$row['ID']]['Count'] += $row['Count'];
                }
                return $result;
            },
            []
        )
    )
);
```

---

If the ID values in the first array are guaranteed to be unique, you can avoid the `array_merge()` call by porting the `$a` array to the result array and assigning temporary keys using the ID values. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kkX2i))

```
$result = array_column($a, null, 'ID');
foreach ($b as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['ID']])) {
        $result[$row['ID']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['ID']]['Count'] += $row['Count'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```